# C# editable listview

Tags: c#, listview

Yesterday I try to implement a new listview that support sub-item edit, my solution is to show a textbox when double click the sub-item. The key code as following:

```
protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
{
        Point pt = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        ListViewItem curItem;
        int subItemIndex = GetSubItemAt(pt.X, pt.Y, out curItem);
        DoubleClickEventArgs args = new DoubleClickEventArgs(subItemIndex);
        base.OnDoubleClick(args);

        if (subItemIndex>=0 && !args.Cancel)
        {
            //StartEdit(...);
        }
```

}

```
public void EndEdit(bool acceptChanges)
    {
        //validation
        .................
        .................
        AfterSubItemEventArgs e = new AfterSubItemEventArgs(this.SelectedItems[0], m_editSubItemIndex, this.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[m_editSubItemIndex].Text, m_textbox.Text, false);
        OnAfterSubItemEdit(e);
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
            //....
        }
        else
        {
            //set new value
        }
        m_textbox.Visible = false;
        m_editSubItemIndex = -1;
    }
```

OnAfterSubItemEdit is a event that user can do some validations or other operations. I add a check in this method, if the new value exist, I will show a messagebox to user firstly, then hide the textbox. But now, the problem comes, when i move the mouse, the listview items can be selected, I don't how to solve this issue, I tried my best to find out the way, but failed. So, please help me!

Comment: Yes, I know the LabelEdit  property, but it only can edit the first sub-item, i want to edit sub-items

Comment: Why not use the DataGridView, you can change the appearance to make it look like a ListView

Comment: yes, i can use the DataGridView instead of Listview，but I still want to solve this issue.

Comment: Oh, ok. SO what exactly is the problem here? Your mouse is blocking input?

Comment: not block, after I close the messagebox, i can selected the listview items by moving the mouse, but normally we need to press the left button and move mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Listview has a LabelEdit property; when you set it "true", then in an event handler you     can call Listview.Items[x].BeginEdit(), and edit an item. As an example, you can handle ListView.DoubleClick event and call BeginEdit right there:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   listView1.LabelEdit = true;
  }

private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if(this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count==1)
     {
       this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I know this property, but it only can edit the first sub-item, i want to edit sub-items

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form still calls the DoubleClick event whether the value exists or not. Add appropriate condition before calling base DoubleClick in your code, i.e.:

```
if(!new value exists)
    base.OnDoubleClick(args);
```